# $addToSet to perform update

Tags: mongodb

Can I use $addToSet to update existing subdocuments?  If so, how can I tell MongoDb that a match is when "oid" and "instance" are the same and the "value" field is what should be updated.

Thanks

```
{ $addToSet : { "data" : { $each : [
 {"oid" : "1.3.6.1.4.1.111.3.10.9.9.88",
      "instance" : "0",
      "value" : "8888"}

{"oid" : "1.3.6.1.4.1.111.3.10.9.9.77",
      "instance" : "0",
      "value" : "88888888"}

 ] } } }



"_id" : 483,
  "data" : [{
      "oid" : "1.3.6.1.4.1.111.3.10.2.5.35.3",
      "instance" : "0",
      "value" : "0"
    }, {
      "oid" : "1.3.6.1.4.1.111.3.999.2.5.2",
      "instance" : "0",
      "value" : "RFCluster"
    }, {
      "oid" : "1.3.6.1.4.1.111.3.30.5.1.1",
      "instance" : "0",
      "value" : null
    }]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use $addToSet to update specific sub-documents only. I think you should change your schema so that each "data" element is a document of its own, and move the ID into a data_id like:

```
{
  "data_id": 483,
  "oid" : "1.3.6.1.4.1.111.3.10.2.5.35.3",
  "instance" : "0",
  "value" : "0"
}
```

Then you can very easily use something like [upsert](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29) to update just one value:

```
db.colname.update(
    { "data_id" 483, "oid" : "1.3.6.1.4.1.111.3.10.2.5.35.3", "instance" : "0" }, // criteria
    { $set: { 'value' : "new value" } }, // update spec
    true // this is to enable "upsert"
);
```